# Laravel 5 Package, Class not found

Tags: php, class, laravel, laravel-5

I have a package folder in which I'm creating a class to help me with an API.
But I'm getting the following error

> Class 'Notflip\Teamleader\Company' not found

I'm trying to access a the Company class by using

```
$companies = new Teamleader\Company();
```

This is my folder structure

[image]

This is my composer.json in my project root

```
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Notflip\\Teamleader\\": "package/Notflip/Teamleader/src"
    }
```

This is my Company class

```
<?php namespace Notflip\Teamleader;

use Notflip\Teamleader;

class Company extends Teamleader {

    public function all()
    {
        return $this->api("getCompanies", ['amount' => 20,'pageno' => 0]);
    }

}
```

Comment: From your folder structure you should be using `namespace Notflip\Teamleader\src\Teamleader` unless you have a custom namespace for `Notflip\Teamleader` set up. If you do then you should include that code in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, including this now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing yourself because you have Teamleader in the namespace definition, and then a Teamleader file and folder. `Notflip\Teamleader\Company` refers to a company file in the src folder.

I'd suggest you edit your composer file to this:

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "Notflip\\": "package/Notflip/Teamleader/src"
}
```

Then rename Teamleader.php to Bootstrap.php or Main.php, or anything like that. For this example I'll rename it to Bootstrap.php. Then in your Company.php file you should have this:

```
<?php namespace Notflip\Teamleader;

use Notflip\Bootstrap;

class Company extends Bootstrap {

    public function all()
    {
        return $this->api("getCompanies", ['amount' => 20,'pageno' => 0]);
    }

}
```

Finally your call to company should look like this:

```
$companies = new \Notflip\Teamleader\Company;
```

Standard practice with Laravel is to ignore the brackets at the end of a new class call if you're not passing in any arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed it. Namespaces keep on confusing me from times to times.

Comment: Your welcome, they took me some time to get used to as well :).

Comment: remember to 'php artisan optimize' to generate the classloader :)